# recursive purrr::modify_depth() does not work on ragged lists

Tags: r, list, recursion, tidyverse, purrr

Say, this is my somewhat convoluted and ragged list:

```
res <- list(
  a = TRUE,
  b = "error msg 1",
  c = list(
    TRUE,
    "error msg 2"
  ),
  d = list(
    e = "error msg 3",
    "error msg 4",  # no name for this list item just to make things interesting
    f = list(
      g = list(
        h = "error msg 5",
        i = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I would now like to, say, apply some function at `2` *depth* (from the top).
My list can be arbitrarily deep and ragged.

I want to be all cool and tidyvers-y, so I though this would work:

```
purrr::modify_depth(.x = res, .depth = 2, .f = str, .ragged = TRUE)
```

But that, unexpectedly, fails with

```
Error in .x[] <- .f(.x, ...) : replacement has length zero
```

Can't make heads nor tails of this, because when I `str()` my way through all the list elements manually, it works just fine; `str()` *does* always give some result.

I am guessing that I'm using `.ragged =` wrong.

I'm also noticing that the same setup works, when using `is.null()` as a function, instead of `str()`, but is then applied to leaves which *don't* actually exist (expanding the list).

```
purrr::modify_depth(.x = res, .depth = 4, .f = is.null, .ragged = TRUE)
```

This creates a list that is *uniformly* 4 deep, though the original is actually quite ragged and only 4 deep down *1* branch.

What I'd *like* to do, is to modify *only those list elements for which a `n` depth actually exists*, and to leave all others unmodified.

How can I get `purrr::modify_depth()` to do that?

Comment: Alistaire has worked out a solution: https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/recursion/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since a satisfying answer is missing here it goes.

First, `str` displays output to the terminal, but does not actually return anything:

```r
is.null(str("anything"))
#>  chr "anything"
#> [1] TRUE
```

The `purrr`-call fails as `.f = str` tries to assign `NULL` values to the list elements, which is not allowed. The error message in the current purrr version (3.4.0) also states this more clearly:

```r
purrr::modify_depth(.x = res, .depth = 2, .f = str, .ragged = TRUE)
#>  logi TRUE
#> Error: Result 1 must be a single logical, not NULL of length 0
```

Replacing `str` by a different function, `purrr` no longer complains:

```r
purrr::modify_depth(.x = res, .depth = 2, .f = is.character, .ragged = TRUE)
#> $a
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "TRUE"
#> 
#> $c
#> $c[[1]]
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $c[[2]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> 
#> $d
#> $d$e
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $d[[2]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $d$f
#> [1] FALSE
```

However, the issue remains that `modify_depth` applies `.f` exactly at `.depth = 2` so any sublists at deeper levels will be collapsed into a logical value by `.f = is.character`

---

Another (non-`purrr`) option could be `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base-`rrapply`) to recurse through a nested list. Setting `how = "replace"` we can modify only elements at a specific depth, while keeping all other list elements unmodified:

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(res, condition = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) == 2, f = function(x) paste(x, "<- modified"), how = "replace")
#> $a
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "error msg 1"
#> 
#> $c
#> $c[[1]]
#> [1] "TRUE <- modified"
#> 
#> $c[[2]]
#> [1] "error msg 2 <- modified"
#> 
#> 
#> $d
#> $d$e
#> [1] "error msg 3 <- modified"
#> 
#> $d[[2]]
#> [1] "error msg 4 <- modified"
#> 
#> $d$f
#> $d$f$g
#> $d$f$g$h
#> [1] "error msg 5"
#> 
#> $d$f$g$i
#> [1] TRUE
```

Here, `condition` decides to which list elements the `f` function is applied and the `.xpos` argument evaluates to the position of the element in the nested list as an integer vector. `length(.xpos)` can then be used to evaluate the depth of any element in the nested list.